# How to use a hidden method in Android?

Tags: android, reflection, sdk

I'm new in Android. My phone has two SIM slots, and I want to know the second SIM card's info. So I want to use the below method in TelephonyManager which is hidden.

[image]

Someone tell me how to use reflect, and here is my try.

```
            Class<TelephonyManager> telephonyManagerClass = TelephonyManager.class;
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            try {
                Method method = telephonyManagerClass.getMethod("getSimState", new Class[]{int.class});
                method.setAccessible(true);
                Object object = method.invoke(telephonyManager,1);
                int a = (int)object;
                System.out.println(a);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Unfortunately, here is exception:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getSimState [int]
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
 at (MainActivity.java:61)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18442)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5195)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:603)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Could you help me to fix it?

Comment: What version of Android are you running under?

Comment: hello, @MikeM. 23.

Comment: Are you running that code directly on your phone, or are you testing it in an emulator?

Comment: @MikeM. on my phone ,my phone is under 4.4,     compileSdkVersion is 23

Comment: Oh, so you're running under KitKat (19), then, not Marshmallow (23).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no support for multiple SIM cards in Android before Lollipop 5.1 (API 22). That method with that signature doesn't exist in KitKat, so your phone is using proprietary software from the manufacturer to handle the dual SIMs. You would most likely have to contact the manufacturer or vendor for information on how to access that functionality, unless you can find something through searches specific to your brand and model.

For reference, [here's that method](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/kitkat-mr2.2-release/telephony/java/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java#863) in the KitKat source, which, you can see, takes no argument for the SIM index. Your reflective method will work if you get the method with no parameters, but that won't help you access state for the second SIM.

Comment: thanks，when i testing it in an emulator which is Lollipop 5.1 (API 22), my method effects.